# pip install xlwings fails

Tags: pip, xlwings

I'm on MacOS Mojave Version 10.14.6, 2.8 GHz Intel Core i7 processor. Python version: 2.7.

"pip install xlwings" fails for me. I have tried to resolve this by upgrading setuptools with `pip install -U setuptools`

However, this does not fix the issue. The full error message for "pip install xlwings" is as follows:

```
Collecting xlwings
  Using cached xlwings-0.16.6.tar.gz (634 kB)
Collecting psutil>=2.0.0
  Using cached psutil-5.9.0.tar.gz (478 kB)
Collecting appscript>=1.0.1
  Using cached appscript-1.2.0.tar.gz (289 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/hm/pt6_h7xs52z7_89jqr614q300000gn/T/pip-install-KTcWya/appscript/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/hm/pt6_h7xs52z7_89jqr614q300000gn/T/pip-install-KTcWya/appscript/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/hm/pt6_h7xs52z7_89jqr614q300000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-fmr2EU
         cwd: /private/var/folders/hm/pt6_h7xs52z7_89jqr614q300000gn/T/pip-install-KTcWya/appscript/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/hm/pt6_h7xs52z7_89jqr614q300000gn/T/pip-install-KTcWya/appscript/setup.py", line 8, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError("Python 3.x required.")
    RuntimeError: Python 3.x required.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xlwings` [declares `appscript` as a dependency](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/blob/44395c4d18b46f76249279b7d0965e640291499c/setup.py#L25) but it doesn't limit version; `appscript` doesn't properly declare Python version compatibility (`xlwings` [does it properly](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/blob/44395c4d18b46f76249279b7d0965e640291499c/setup.py#L69)) so `pip` is trying to install the latest version which is not compatible with Python 2.7. Try to limit versions this way:

```
pip install "xlwings<0.17" "appscript<1.2"
```

Comment: This worked, thank you so much!!